# Применение категорий для RFM анализа и повышения LTV

Tags: python, big-data, анализ, аналитика, маркетинг

Вопрос очень общий. Но я пока не понимаю, в какую сторону двигаться. Я провожу анализ частоты, давности и размера денежной суммы покупок клиентов с целью повышения срока взаимодействия клиента с компанией. К основной таблице с данными о пользователях прилагается таблица с категориями товаров, причем каждая категория должна быть привязана к определенной покупке. В таблице параметры:

```
 id  parent_id  Hyper_Cat_id  Путь к каталогу
123   234        45532        /товары для дома/товары для кухни/посуда/кастрюли
```

Вот такое дерево категорий. Причем что такое parent_id и id я не понимаю, так как проверила кодом, что ни одно parent_id не входит в id. Hyper_Cat_id - может, кто с таким сталкивался? Id гиперкаталога? Зачем дается parent_id, если он не связан с id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не видя ваших данных, мы можем только строить догадки...

Мои догадки:

1. `parent_id` - указывает на "родительскую" (более общую) категорию в той же или во внешней таблице.
2. `Hyper_Cat_id` - ссылка на первичный ключ (если речь идёт о БД) связанного "гиперкаталога"

Если под таблицами в вопросе понимаются таблицы реляционной БД, то стоит проверить внешние ключи (`FOREIGN KEYS`) таблиц - они помогут увидеть связи с другими таблицами.

Если речь идёт о `big data` данных, то надо смотреть документацию, спрашивать коллег и т.д.

Comment: У меня нет никакой базы данных - просто таблицы, так сказать, для справки к основным данным о пользователях. Спрошу у тех, кто мне давал задание, спасибо!)